# Обход дерева с вызовом действий в узлах

Tags: java, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня есть дерево, узлы которого имеют тип `Node`. В зависимости от типа (одной из реализаций `Node`) узлы различаются набором информации, которая в них хранится. У меня также есть действия `Action`, которые должны вызываться при посещении определенного типа узла. Действия каким-то образом регистрируются, затем происходит проход по дереву.

Пример действия:

```
public final class ActionA extends Action {
    @Override
    public void act(final NodeA node) {
        System.out.println("Act action1 (" + node.value() + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeB node) {
        System.out.println("Act action1 (" + node.value() + ")");
    }
}
```

Код этих методов должен выполниться, при посещении узлов типа `NodeA` и `NodeB`. Помогите реализовать или расскажите как лучше это реализовать с точки зрения архитектуры.

Comment: То, что вы хотите, реализуется паттерном [Visitor](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Comment: @Nofate, разве тогда не нужно будет добавить дополнительную логику или пустой метод, для всех остальных нод или что-то еще?

Comment: @ИванГладуш, можно сделать `Action` не интерфейсом, а классом, определить там методы для всех типов узлов (без поведения), а потом в наследниках переопределять по необходимости, я думаю.

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

С использованием паттерна Visitor:

```
class Node {

    protected final Node[] childs;

    public Node() {
        this(new Node[] {});
    }

    public Node(final Node[] childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }

    public Node[] childs() {
        return this.childs;
    }

    public void accept(final Action visitor) {
        for (final Node child : childs()) {
            child.accept(visitor);
        }
        visitor.act(this);
    }
}

interface Action {
    default void act(final Node node) {
        if (node instanceof NodeA) {
            this.act((NodeA) node);
        } else if (node instanceof NodeB) {
            this.act((NodeB) node);
        }
        else if (node instanceof NodeC) {
            this.act((NodeC) node);
        } else if (node instanceof NodeD) {
            this.act((NodeD) node);
        }
    }
    default void act(final NodeB node) {}
    default void act(final NodeA node) {}
    default void act(final NodeC node) {}
    default void act(final NodeD node) {}
}

class NodeA extends Node {
    public NodeA(final Node[] elements) {
        super(elements);
    }
}

class NodeB extends Node {}
class NodeC extends Node {}
class NodeD extends Node {}

class ActionA implements Action {

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeB node) {
        System.out.println("Action A / Node B");
    }

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeA node) {
        System.out.println("Action A / Node A");
    }
}

class ActionB implements Action {

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeC node) {
        System.out.println("Action B / Node C");
    }

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeD node) {
        System.out.println("Action B / Node D");
    }
}

public class ApplicationDemo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Node node = new NodeA(new Node[]{
                new NodeB(), new NodeD(),
                new NodeB(), new NodeC()
        });

        node.accept(new ActionB());
        node.accept(new ActionA());
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Action B / Node D
Action B / Node C
Action A / Node B
Action A / Node B
Action A / Node A
```